# Vue.js router transition fade gap

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, animate.css

I'm using the amazing transition to slide router pages in vue.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <header-comp></header-comp>
    <transition
            name="custom-classes-transition"
            mode="out-in"
            enter-active-class="animated slideInLeft"
            leave-active-class="animated slideOutRight"
    >
        <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
    <footer-comp></footer-comp>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
    @import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.1';
</style>
```

It works very nice and smooth, but... the new coming page enter when the first one is totally gone. This made a gap between transition.

In Vue manual:  [Transition-Modes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes) there are a few examples. I need to replicate the third button example but I'm missing the mode I have to use.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your transitioning elements is that you want them to occupy the same space in DOM at the same time (even if, visually, one enters and one exists - that's only done through `transforms` but the two elements need to occupy the same space in DOM).

Therefore you need to give one of them `position:absolute` and use CSS to size and position it correctly, to match the exact position and size it would have when not having `position:absolute` (which is what it will have when not trasitioning).

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-w3iem). Note yours might need different styles applied to a different element.
Since you haven't provided a minimal, reproducible example with your own markup, there's no way to know.

In the example above, I gave the subsequent `<div>` (the entering one)

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 60px;
left: 0;
```

If you choose to wrap all your `<router-view>`s into a common wrapper element with `position:relative`, `top` would need to be `0` (in the example `60px` is accounting for `<nav>`'s height).

**Note:** *and **yes**, as others already pointed, you don't need `mode="in-out"`. But that still leaves you with the positioning issue.*

---

**Edit:** I've played with two more examples.

- one [using a flexbox container](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-qodjc) of `height:100vh` where top and bottom elements don't grow and middle one does. When middle element is too big, it becomes scrollable.
- [another one](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-b9wwh) where I played with the transition effects and Bootstrap Vue.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. It works nice but I have to adjust the footer fixing it to the bottom. I try "style="position: relative; bottom: 0;" in footer div but it not works. I used mode in-out just  because it helps instead of the position absolute but... it created the gap

Comment: Well, if you want to transition inside an element placed between other two variable elements, you'll need to go with a flexbox container of `height: 100vh`. [Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-qodjc).

Comment: Thanks for your time Andrei, your both examples are great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually since you don't need any special behaviour and actually want both transitions to happen at the same time, you shouldn't be using the `mode` at all. Just remove it and it should work as you described. From the docs link you pasted:

> Simultaneous entering and leaving transitions aren’t always desirable though, so Vue offers some alternative transition modes
>
> - in-out: New element transitions in first, then when complete, the current element transitions out.
> - out-in: Current element transitions out first, then when complete, the new element transitions in.

Comment: If I remove the mode I have only transition OUT then page 2 without IN effect. Not sure if it is an issue using transition on the router

Answer (score 0):

`mode="in-out"`: New element transitions in first, then when complete, the current element transitions out.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    showOn: true
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      console.log(this.message);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}

#app {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <transition  name="slide-fade" mode="in-out">
      <button v-if="showOn"
        key="on"
      type="button"
      @click="showOn=false">On</button>
      <button v-else type="button"
      key="off"
      @click="showOn=true">Off</button>
    </transition>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, BigLiao. This removes the gap but has a little flickering on the slide, but it's a going point. Thanks